# Why does select in golang only works with channels in goroutine?

Tags: go, channel

Consider the following [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M_ui4GNMMw)

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        messages := make(chan string)

        messages <- "my msg"

        select {
        case msg := <-messages:
            fmt.Println("received message", msg)
        }

    }
```

The code above will reach error

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

However

if I change it to

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        messages := make(chan string)

        go func() {
            messages <- "my msg"
        }()
        select {
        case msg := <-messages:
            fmt.Println("received message", msg)
        }

    }
```

It will work.

Is there a particular reason for this behavior?

Shouldn't the code execute in a sequential manner in the first case so that by the time the select statement is reached, the msg will be passed and it will catch the case `msg := <-messages` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't the code execute in a sequential manner in the first case so that by the time the select statement is reached, the msg will be passed and it will catch the case msg := <-messages ?

The select statement is never reached, thats the problem in your first code.

The statement

```
messages <- "my msg"
```

Wants to push a string into the channel, but since you created a unbuffered channel

```
messages := make(chan string)
```

the goroutine keeps waiting for someone to actually read from the channel, so it can push the string to the channel. You can **only** push something to a unbuffered channel **if** there is somewhere a goroutine reading from it!

Try the first example with a buffered channel:

```
messages := make(chan string, 1)
```

It should work as you expected.